# Mock Api Responses in Android Testing

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

I'm looking for a way to mock api responses in android tests.

I have read the roboelectric could be used for this but I would really appreciate any advice on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a small bit of looking around on the web I have found [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) to be what I was looking for.

> A scriptable web server for testing HTTP clients. This library makes it easy to test that your app Does The Right Thing when it makes HTTP and HTTPS calls. It lets you specify which responses to return and then verify that requests were made as expected.

To get setup just add the following to your **build.gradle** file.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.google.mockwebserver:mockwebserver:20130706'
```

Here is a simple example taking from their GitHub page.

```
public void test() throws Exception {
    // Create a MockWebServer. These are lean enough that you can create a new
    // instance for every unit test.
    MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();

    // Schedule some responses.
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("hello, world!"));

    // Start the server.
    server.play();

    // Ask the server for its URL. You'll need this to make HTTP requests.
    URL baseUrl = server.getUrl("/v1/chat/");

    // Exercise your application code, which should make those HTTP requests.
    // Responses are returned in the same order that they are enqueued.
    Chat chat = new Chat(baseUrl);

    chat.loadMore();
    assertEquals("hello, world!", chat.messages());

    // Shut down the server. Instances cannot be reused.
    server.shutdown();
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What does `20130706` stand for??

Answer (score 4):

MockWebServer didn't work for me with AndroidTestCase. For instance, ECONNREFUSED error happened quite randomly (described in https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1069). I didn't try Robolectric.

As of OkHttp 2.2.0, I found an alternative way which worked well for me: Interceptors. I placed the whole mock response inside a json file stored on `androidTest/assets/`, say, 'mock_response.json'. When I instanced an OkHttp for testing, I exposed an Interceptor which I would rewrite the incoming response. Basically, body() would instead stream the data in 'mock_response.json'.

```java
public class FooApiTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    public void testFetchData() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        // mock_response.json is placed on 'androidTest/assets/'
        final InputStream stream = getContext().getAssets().open("mock_response.json");

        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        httpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                return new Response.Builder()
                        .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_2)
                        // This is essential as it makes response.isSuccessful() returning true.
                        .code(200)
                        .request(chain.request())
                        .body(new ResponseBody() {
                            @Override
                            public MediaType contentType() {
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public long contentLength() {
                                // Means we don't know the length beforehand.
                                return -1;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public BufferedSource source() {
                                try {
                                    return new Buffer().readFrom(stream);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    return null;
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .build();
            }
        });

        FooApi api = new FooApi(httpClient);
        api.fetchData();

        // TODO: Let's assert the data here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is now even easier with [Mockinizer](https://github.com/donfuxx/Mockinizer) which makes working with MockWebServer easier:

```
val mocks: Map<RequestFilter, MockResponse> = mapOf(

    RequestFilter("/mocked") to MockResponse().apply {
        setResponseCode(200)
        setBody("""{"title": "Banana Mock"}""")
    },

    RequestFilter("/mockedError") to MockResponse().apply {
        setResponseCode(400)
    }

)
```

Just create a map of RequestFilter and MockResponses and then plug it into your OkHttpClient builder chain:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .mockinize(mocks) // <-- just plug in your custom mocks here
            .build()
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try [Beeceptor's HTTP Proxy](https://beeceptor.com/docs/forward-proxy-with-mock/). It is a hosted HTTP proxy helps you record the traffic between the mobile app and the server, and then lets you selectively mock a few/all calls. This way you can have a deterministic testing ON or OFF at your wish, and compare the app's behavior.

I am adding an image for quick understanding, how it intercepts HTTP traffic originating from the mobile app and gives you view and modify capabilities.

[image]